# How to change semantic ui icon colour to defined colour in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I use [semantic ui for react](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/icon/) where I use different icons. One of these icons however must have a different colour. 
We can change the colour by props

```
 <Icon name="play" color="red"/>
```

Something I really want to do is change the color from a pattern that I created. I have the pattern in a .png and I tried different methods, including:

```
<Icon name="play" style={{color: url('./path_to_image')}}
```

But it fails. Any ideas how I could change the colour of an icon to a self defined pattern?

I also found a potential solution where I create the .svg image by myself and then style it but I would love to find something more straightforward rather than 'reinventing the wheel'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to accomplish what you are trying to do with props. Additionally, the `color` css attribute you are trying to apply does not accept a path.

You can probably accomplish this with the icons in Semantic UI but your solution may not work as expected in all browsers. You'll need to know that the icons in Semantic UI are actually a font (from FontAwesome). Therefore, you can't use any SVG solutions unless you bring your own SVG based icon components.

Your best bet will probably be to use `-webkit-background-clip: text` [though not all browsers support this, and you have to use the unofficial prefix](https://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts).

[CSS Tricks has a good tutorial on how to do this](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-do-knockout-text/). You'll also see in the tutorial that [all the other solutions to accomplish this are SVG based](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-do-knockout-text/#article-header-id-2).